# Network Login Page for telstra

Tags: internet-explorer

How can I create a page for a network like in hotels or McDonald's so once you connect the admin has to supply a password or code so that the guest can log but has a data limit of say 3 gb in and also have an admin code to login to the network with unlimeted usage amount.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may need to give a bit more detail about what you are trying to do, what you have tried already, and what your specific problem is. Overly broad questions, or questions that don't show prior research, are likely to be downvoted and/or closed. Please take a look at the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something called a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Have a bit of a read of this and hopefully a little research will find you a product that suits your needs.